# RxAndroid filter Observable<List<Item>>

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I use RxAndroid and I'd like to filter the result of an `Observable<List<Item>>`.

Here is the code :

```
Observable<List<Item>> observable = 
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Item>>) subscriber -> {
        subscriber.onNext(ItemManager.getItems());
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    });
```

I would like to use `.filter()` to only get the valid items. Doing this would be perfect :

```
observable.filter(new Func1<Item, Boolean>() {
    @Override
        public Boolean call(Item item) {
            return item.isValid();
    }
});
```

However, `.filter()` forces me to implement new Func1() :

```
observable.filter(new Func1<List<Item>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
            public Boolean call(Item item) {
        }
    });
```

Does somebody know how to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(ItemManager.getItems())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .filter(item -> item.isValid())
            .toList();
```

Comment: I forgot to say that ItemManager.getItems() must be called asynchronously because it make a Network call :/

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This way he isn't calling `ItemManager.getItems()` asynchronously, but processing its results asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the `defer()` call, +1 to your answer ;-)

Comment: You may want to use `Observable.fromCallable` instead of `Observable.defer` + `Observable.just`. Or you may want to use `Observable.defer` + `Observable.from` and drop the `flatMapIterable`. (OIr just stay like this !)

Comment: Here's a post detailing the different ways and implications of using defer and fromCallable https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/

Comment: Does this creates a list of valid objects? It doesn't work for me if I use a condition like object.getField() != null

Answer (score 0):

Just create the Observable with the from function:

```
    Observable<Item> observable = Observable.from(ItemManager.getItems())
    .filter(new Func1<Item, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Item item) {
            return item.isValid();
        }
    });

    observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

**UPDATE**:

Since you need `ItemManager.getItems()` to be called asynchronously you need to do:

```
Observable<List<Item>> observable = 
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Item>) subscriber -> {
        for (Item item : ItemManager.getItems()) {
            subscriber.onNext(item);
        }

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    })
.filter(item -> item.isValid())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

This way the subscription, and the call to `ItemManager.getItems()`, will be performed on an io thread.

Comment: I forgot to say that ItemManager.getItems() must be called asynchronously because it make a Network call :/

Comment: I'd really recommend avoiding `Observable.create` in every case when it's possible.

Comment: @Geralt_Encore why ?

Comment: It's a good piece of advice. If you create your own Obserable with create you have to deal with errors and completion on your own.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution but I don't know if this is the good way to do it :

```
Observable<List<Item>> observable = 
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<Item>) subscriber -> {
        for (Item item : ItemManager.getItems()) {
            subscriber.onNext(item);
        }

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    })
    .filter(item -> item.isValid());
```